# Show N number of characters in Laravel using PHP

Tags: php, string, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to show N number of characters in my Laravel website using PHP. For that I have used string function `str_limit()`

> {!! str_limit($data->details ,'40') !!}

But No data is shown in the site though `$data->details` has value. If I use `{{ $data->details }}` then it shows the whole value. But I want N number characters in the website.

Any help please....
If any further questions to clarify please ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think you're putting the truncation number in quotes when it's not supposed to be.

```
{{ str_limit(strip_tags($data->details), 40) }}
```

Comment: @Polaris....My value contains `<p>Hello this is the value</p>`.....That's why I used `htmlspecialchars_decode()`...so my total function is `{!! str_limit(htmlspecialchars_decode($latest_news[0]->details), '40') !!}`

Comment: @ArafatRahman Are you trying to not count the HTML as part of the 40 characters? Also, the number 40 should still not be in single quotes.

Comment: no I don't want to count html part within 40 characters

Comment: @ArafatRahman I edited the code to remove all HTML tags, so the count won't be a part of the 40 characters. Try my above code and let me know the output. You now said $latest_news[0]->details was the variable with the data in it, but in the original post said it was $data->details? Try whichever one it is and report back please.

Comment: Ya....That's correct !! Both `{{ str_limit(strip_tags($data->details), 40) }}` and `{!! str_limit(strip_tags($data->details), 40) !!}` are correct....
Thanks a lot my friend :)